# Using a function as an argument in another function through decorators

Tags: python, function, decorator

Here is the code:

```
def smart_divide(func):
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
        print("Whoops! cannot divide")
      else:
        return func(a,b)
   return inner

@smart_divide
def divide(c,d):
    return c/d

divide(5,2)
```

This is a program to divide two numbers and give an error message if the denominator is 0.

We are passing 5 and 2 as an argument to the function divide. How does `inner` function know that the value of a and b is 5 and 2 respectively?

According to what I read on internet : `@smart_divide` means that `divide = smart_divide(divide(c,d))`

The function `divide` has parameters c,d while the function `inner` has parameters a,b. How does the interpreter know that a = c and b = d?

Comment: It doesn't mean `divide = smart_divide(divide(c,d))`, since smart_divide accepts a function while divide(c,d) would be a number.

Comment: Your statement `divide(5,2)` actually calls `inner(5,2)` which then calls the wrapped definition of `divide()` passing 5 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

`@smart_divide` means that

```
result = smart_divide(divide)(c,d)
```

That means, `divide` no points to `inner` function, and `inner` function calls the original function `divide` via `func`.

Answer (score 0):

`divide = smart_divide(divide(c,d))` is not really a good description of what happens.  Have a look at the logical expansion step by step, in some kind of pseudo-Python:

```
divide(x, y)
= smart_divide(lambda c, d: c / d)(x, y)
= inner[func ~> lambda c, d: c / d](x, y)
= (def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
        print("Whoops! cannot divide")
      else:
        return (lambda c, d: c / d)(a, b))(x, y)
= print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
  if y == 0:
      print("Whoops! cannot divide")
  else:
      return (lambda c, d: c / d)(x, y))
= print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
  if y == 0:
      print("Whoops! cannot divide")
  else:
      return x / y
```

The important thing that happens is *lexical scoping*.  If you substitute an expression in another expression (the `~>` operation above), then you assume that the names don't get mangled.  That is, `(lambda a: lambda b: a)(b))` does not become `lambda b: b`, but (something equivalent to) `lambda b_prime: b`. Names don't matter: this is called [alpha equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of decorators is almost right, this should clarify things.

The code in your example:

```
@smart_divide
def divide(c,d):
    return c/d
```

Is functionally identical to:

```
def simple_div(c,d):
    return c/d

divide = smart_divide(simple_div)
```

`divide` is defined as the `inner` of the `smart_divide` decorator.
`smart_divide` is given `simple_div` as a parameter (`func`), which is what `inner` uses to call the originally decorated `simple_div` method.

Furthermore: `smart_divide` can be used to decorate multiple functions because a new `inner` function is created each time `smart_divide` is called, so the `func` reference is different each time.